# inner labelling for heatmap, in R ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, heatmap, complexheatmap

I am trying to add a number label on each cell of a heatmap. Because it also needs marginal barcharts I have tried two packages. iheatmapr and ComplexHeatmap.

(1st try) iheatmapr makes it easy to add to add bars as below, but I couldnt see how to add labels inside the heatmap on individual cells.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(iheatmapr)
library(RColorBrewer)

in_out <- data.frame(
  'Economic' = c(2,1,1,3,4),
  'Education' = c(0,3,0,1,1),
  'Health' = c(1,0,1,2,0),
  'Social' = c(2,5,0,3,1) )
rownames(in_out) <- c('Habitat', 'Resource', 'Combined', 'Protected', 'Livelihood')

GreenLong <- colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(9, 'Greens'))(12)
lowGreens <- GreenLong[0:5]

in_out_matrix <- as.matrix(in_out)
main_heatmap(in_out_matrix, colors = lowGreens)

in_out_plot <- iheatmap(in_out_matrix,
  colors=lowGreens) %>% 
  add_col_labels() %>% 
  add_row_labels() %>% 
  add_col_barplot(y = colSums(bcio)/total) %>% 
  add_row_barplot(x = rowSums(bcio)/total)
in_out_plot
```

Then used: save_iheatmap(in_out_plot, "iheatmapr_test.png")
Because I couldnt use ggsave(device = ragg::agg_png etc) with iheatmapr object.

[image: saved with iheatmap]

Also, the iheatmapr object's apparent incompatibility (maybe I am wrong) with ggsave() is a problem for me because I normally use ragg package to export image AGG to preserve font sizes. I am suspecting some other heatmap packages make custom objects that maybe incompatible with patchwork and ggsave.

```
ggsave("png/iheatmapr_test.png", plot = in_out_plot,
       device = ragg::agg_png, dpi = 72,
       units="in", width=3.453, height=2.5,
       scaling = 0.45)
```

(2nd try) ComplexHeatmap makes it easy to label individual number "cells" inside a heatmap, and also offers marginal bars among its "Annotations", and I have tried it, but its colour palette system (which uses integers to refer to a set of colours) doesnt suit my RGB vector colour gradient, and overall it is a sophisticated package clearly designed to make graphics more advanced than what I am doing.

I am aiming for style as shown in screenshot example below, which was made in Excel.
[image: Excel heatmap with bars and labelled cells]

Please can anyone suggest a more suitable R package for a simple heatmap like this with marginal bars, and number labels inside?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of relying on packages which offer out-of-the-box solutions one option to achieve your desired result would be to create your plot from scratch using `ggplot2` and `patchwork` which gives you much more control to style your plot, to add labels and so on.

Note: The issue with `iheatmapr` is that it returns a `plotly` object, not a ggplot. That's why you can't use ggsave.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(patchwork)

in_out <- data.frame(
  'Economic' = c(1,1,1,5,4),
  'Education' = c(0,0,0,1,1),
  'Health' = c(1,0,1,0,0),
  'Social' = c(1,1,0,3,1) )
rownames(in_out) <- c('Habitat', 'Resource', 'Combined', 'Protected', 'Livelihood')

in_out_long <- in_out %>% 
  mutate(y = rownames(.)) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-y, names_to = "x")

# Summarise data for marginal plots
yin <- in_out_long %>% 
  group_by(y) %>% 
  summarise(value = sum(value)) %>% 
  mutate(value = value / sum(value))

xin <- in_out_long %>% 
  group_by(x) %>% 
  summarise(value = sum(value)) %>% 
  mutate(value = value / sum(value))

# Heatmap
ph <- ggplot(in_out_long, aes(x, y, fill = value)) +
  geom_tile() +
  geom_text(aes(label = value), size = 8 / .pt) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "#F7FCF5", high = "#00441B") +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL, fill = NULL)

# Marginal plots
py <- ggplot(yin, aes(value, y)) +
  geom_col(width = .75) +
  geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent(value)), hjust = -.1, size = 8 / .pt) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(.0, .25))) +
  theme_void()

px <- ggplot(xin, aes(x, value)) +
  geom_col(width = .75) +
  geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent(value)), vjust = -.5, size = 8 / .pt) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(.0, .25))) +
  theme_void()

# Glue plots together
px + plot_spacer() + ph + py + plot_layout(ncol = 2, widths = c(2, 1), heights = c(1, 2))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Stefan, the code works well; and I will take on board a principle of  using ggplot raw as far as possible before resorting to heatmap packages.